# Relation between the $t$-derivative of the pullback of a form $\omega$ by the flow $f_t$ and the Lie derivative of $\omega$ along the generator

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-derivative, pullback

at the moment I am self-studying differential geometry using the [book by Guillemin and Haine](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.952/2018SP/files/18.952_book.pdf). In this book, Exercise 2.6.ix asks me to prove the following:

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open, $f_t: U \to U, t \in \mathbb{R}$, a one-parameter group of diffeomorphisms and (the vector field) $\boldsymbol{v}$ its infinitesimal generator. Given $\omega \in \Omega^k(U)$, show that
$$ \left. \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}f_t^\star \omega\right\vert_{t=0} = L_\boldsymbol{v}\omega,\qquad\qquad(*) $$
where $L_\boldsymbol{v}\omega := \mathrm{d}\iota_\boldsymbol{v}\omega + \iota_\boldsymbol{v}\mathrm{d}\omega$ is the Lie derivative and $f_t^\star \omega$ is the pullback of $\omega$ by $f_t$.

Some more context:

They give a sketch of the proof: (1) Show that ($*$) holds for zero-forms. (2) Show that if ($*$) holds for some $k$-form $\omega$, it also holds for $\mathrm d\omega$. (3) Show that if holds for $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$, it also holds for $\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2$. (4) Show that ($*$) thus holds for general forms, since they are a wedge product of zero-forms and exact one-forms.

(Importantly, in the next Exercise one uses the result ($*$) to show that ($*$) holds also for all $t$, and that the Lie-derivative $L_\boldsymbol{v}$ commutes with $f^\star_t$.
I see that in the literature ($*$) for all $t$ is used as a *definition* of the Lie-derivative. However, for solving the exercise I can only work with what I stated above.)

I have a hard time proving point (2), and would appreciate some feedback to make my prove correct or point me to what I am missing. Judging from the structure of the exercises so far, I expect the proof can be done in a couple of lines.

My attempt at a proof looks like this:

**Claim:**

If ($*$) holds for $\omega$, then
$$ \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}f_t^\star \mathrm{d}\omega\right\vert_{t=0} = L_\boldsymbol{v}\mathrm{d}\omega,\qquad\qquad(2). $$

**Proof (attempt):**

First, by differentiating $f^\star_t \mathrm{d}\omega = \mathrm{d}f^\star_t\omega$ with respect to $t$, and then evaluating at $t=0$, the LHS of (2) becomes:
$$ LHS(2) = \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathrm{d}f^\star_t \omega\right\vert_{t=0}.$$

By using $L_\boldsymbol{v}\mathrm{d}\omega = \mathrm{d}L_\boldsymbol{v}\omega$ (which follows directly from the definition of the Lie derivative) together with the assumption, the RHS becomes
$$ RHS(2) = \mathrm{d}\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}f^\star_t \omega\right\vert_{t=0}.$$

So, I am done if I show that
$$ \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathrm{d}f^\star_t \omega\right\vert_{t=0} = \mathrm{d}\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}f^\star_t \omega\right\vert_{t=0}.\qquad\qquad(**)$$

So now the wonky bit:

I assumed (maybe wrongly) that for $p \in U$ the pullback $f^\star_t \omega$ has the form
$$ (f^\star_t \omega)_{p} = \sum_I (a_I\circ f_t)(p) \mathrm{d}x_I.\qquad\qquad(***)$$.

What I mean by that is that if $\omega = \sum_I \Phi_I \mathrm{d}x_I$, then
$$f_t^\star \omega = \sum_I (\Phi_I \circ f_t) \mathrm{d}(x_I \circ f_t) = \sum_I (\Phi_I \circ f_t) \mathrm{d}f_{t,i_{1}} \wedge \dots \wedge \mathrm{d}f_{t,i_{k}} \\ 
= \sum_I (\Phi_I \circ f_t) \sum_{j_1} (\frac{\partial f_{t,i_{1}}}{\partial x_{j_1}} \circ f_t) \mathrm{d}x_{j_1} \wedge \dots \wedge \sum_{j_k} (\frac{\partial f_{t,i_{k}}}{\partial x_{j_k}} \circ f_t) \mathrm{d}x_{j_k} \\
= \sum_I (\Phi_I \circ f_t) \left(\prod_{l=1}^k \left(\frac{\partial f_{t,i_{k}}}{\partial x_{j_k}} \circ f_t\right)\right) \bigwedge_{l=1}^k \mathrm{d}x_{j_l}\\
=: \sum_I (a_I\circ f_t) \mathrm{d}x_I,
$$
where $a_I$ is just some function defined by the last equality.
This $a_I$ incorporates the sums and products of $\Phi_I$, the partial derivatives of the $f_{t,i}$ and the orthogonality and redundancy of the basis elements.
Since all these functions are $C^\infty$, this combination can be written as a $C^\infty$-function $a_I$.

Then, after some explicit calculation using chain and product rules for functions, and the fact that $\gamma(t) = f_t(p)$ is an integral curve starting at $p$ for $t=0$, and thus  $\left(\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(f_t)\right\vert_{t=0}\right)_i = \left(\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}\gamma(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}\right\vert_{t=0}\right)_i=v_i$, I could explicitly calculate that both sides of ($**$) agree.

However, I still haven't been able to properly show ($***$). Also, I have the feeling that I am overcomplicating things and trying to do too much in coordinates.

Can you help me simplify or complete my proof?

Comment: $(***)$ is false. If $f$ is a function, then $f^*(a_i dx^i) = (a_i\circ f)d(x^i\circ f)$. More generally, $(f^*\omega)_p(v_1,\ldots,v_k) = \omega_{f(p)}(df_p(v_1),\ldots,df_p(v_k))$.

Comment: Just so you know: This is not a book about differential geometry at all. Differential forms are a topic in multivariable calculus/analysis and do appear in working with manifolds and differential geometry in a more advanced setting. Guillemin's definition is odd here: the Lie derivative is usually defined by the left-hand side, and the formula (usually called the Cartan formula) with interior and exterior derivatives is then proved.

Comment: Hello @Didier,
I was thinking about your comment. Surely, if $\omega = \sum_I \Phi_I \mathrm{d}x_I$, in general $f^\star \omega \not= \sum_I(\Phi_I \circ f) \mathrm{d}x_I$.
I was more thinking about some different function on the basis elements.
I edited my post to make this more clear.

Comment: @TedShifrin I know that it is mostly about differential forms and spends lots of time on euclidean differential calculus as a motivation, but in later chapters generalizes to manifolds.
I just thought that starting from something I know without having to dive too deep into topology to get a notion of differential forms would be suitable.
Do you have another recommendation for a  (freely available) book?

Comment: You don’t need any of this. You have a differential form on $\Bbb R^n$ whose coefficients also depend on $t$. Smoothness tells you that $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t\partial x_i} =\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i\partial t}.$$